# can not seed supabase using Prisma in nextjs project

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, prisma, supabase

I can not seed supabase database using Prisma from my project

I added seed script in package.json

```
"prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
},
```

In seeding file
deleting previous records then create many entries.

```
await client.category.deleteMany();

const categories = await client.category.createMany({
    data: [
        {
            name: "swimming",
        },
    ],
});
```

but get error:

> Error: Command was
> killed with SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault): ts-node --compiler-options
> {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts

Comment: I am getting that error, that's why i got to this post. But {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} is not compatible with typescript right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`supabase` will give you connection string options, chose the `URI` and paste it to the `env` file that created by `npx prisma init`. After you successfully set schema, make sure this runs `npx prisma db push` without error.

Then in `pages/api/seed.ts` api file, write this

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
   await client.category.deleteMany();

   const categories = await client.category.createMany({
    data: [
        {
            name: "swimming",
        },
    ],
});

res.status(200).json({ message: "successfully seeded" });    
}
```

Then visit, `http://localhost:3000/api/seed` this api function will be executed